# 503 Server Unavailable - Dynamics CRM Web Service down - how to diagnose?

Tags: soap, web, service, crm, microsoft-dynamics

I provide support for a large application across multiple servers.  System has been running live for 6+ months.

8th December: total system failure.  iisreset across each of the servers sorted it out.  Everything back to normal.

Post failure investigation showed various processes not able to get a response from a particular server which hosts an instance of Dynamics CRM (2011 R11).  Specifically it seems the SOAP service was not responding (Organization.svc).  503 - Server Unavailable (really it was just the web service).  I suspect it died.

Having the exact time of the error I checked the event logs on the server but these did not have anything of use.  The last error prior to the failure was a report rendering error which was 9 minutes before the system actually went down.  Surely if web service crashed this would be reflected in the event log?

Fast forward to today, 8th January and the system fails again.  The 8th of the month again!  iisreset fixes it... again!

Again, completely useless event logs showings no errors prior to failure.

Entertained the idea of Dynamics CRM trace logging but this is out of the question due to the performance hit.

Apart from the event logs where else to look?  Are there possible external factors or causes?  I'm trying to find the root cause but have run out of ideas!

Comment: Further info in response to Shane below, seems the App pool is being recycled every 1740 minutes (possible Dynamics default setting during install?).

Answer (score 1):

While this may not address the source of your problem, maybe it can help minimize the symptoms. May I suggest that you configure the IIS server to recycle the application pool at a scheduled interval within your production environment.

http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc753179%28v=ws.10%29.aspx